# “Clear All” shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA, sbt-shell window

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, sbt, key

Anybody knows a short-key with which we can do a **Clear all** in **sbt-shell**?

Comment: General **Clear all** key does not work with sbt-shell.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. What shortcut did you try? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: When the prompt is focused, shortcut does not work. (IDEA-COMMUNITY 2018.1)

Comment: Please check the latest stable build (2018.3.5) or 2019.1 EAP

Comment: You are right @y.bedrov it is solved in the latest version. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved in Intellij 2018.3.5+.
Generic `Clear All` works for sbt-shell as well.